# Runtime Errors Android: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android, resources, runtime

I am getting some errors when trying to code my android project and run it.

These are the errors that I am receiving at runtime: no matter how many times i clean the project:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:724)
at com.example.shannon.popular.BreedAdapter.getView(BreedAdapter.java:38)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
```

BreedAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.shannon.popular;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.List;


class BreedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Breed> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Breed> breeds;


    BreedAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Breed> breeds) {
        super(context, resource, breeds);
        this.context = context;
        this.breeds = breeds;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.breed, null);
        Breed breed = breeds.get(position);
        String breedName = breed.getNameString(context);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.breedNameText)).setText(breedName);
        String uri = "@drawable/" + breedName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.breedImageView);
        Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        image.setImageDrawable(res);
        return view;
    }
}
```

can anybody explain what they think these could mean?

Thank you

Comment: post `BreedAdapter.java` and point out line 38

Comment: I edited the question to show the Adapter class and this is line 38 :  Drawable res = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

Comment: what happens you replace  `int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
` with `context.getResources().getIdentifier(breedName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_"), "drawable", context.getPackageName());`

Comment: @coder123 iirc you are not supposed to include the `@` in type name. change `"@drawable/"` to `"drawable/"`

Comment: ok and do i take out line 38?

Comment: @coder123 He said to replace the line.